# Chrome behaving differently on two identical VM

Tags: google-chrome, cpu-usage

I'm currently using two different VPS which are made of the same components.

-On those two VPS the same amount of tabs are oppened with the exact same extensions and the same chrome version.

-One of them is running 25 chrome threads while the other one is running more than 50, which cause CPU usage spikes and obviously crashes.

I would like to know why are they behaving differently while having the same characteristics, where should i look to be able able to fix that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One of them is running **25 chrome threads** while the **other one is
> running more than 50**, which cause CPU usage spikes and obviously
> crashes.

So usage is **different**.  Number 2 is using twice the threads and so roughly twice the memory. All browsers chew up memory as more tabs get opened.

Now a VM generally has hard limits of memory (my VMs are like that). So the OS will start paging internally to make up for the lack of memory in the VM.

I suspect that as paging increases, that is what is causing the crash. Certainly make sure page file setups are equal. That should help the machines perform nearly equally in this case.

Try number 2 with 25 threads and it should work just like number 1.

Comment: First thank you for your answer, the thing is i don't have a word to say about the threads. 15 tabs are open on both VM. The first one is running 25 chrome threads for those 15 tabs while the 2nd need 50. i tried to change chrome version, reinstall it etc but nothing changes, it still open 50 threads to run the 15 tabs.

Comment: There must be something different. Some extension added another extension?  The additional memory used will cause the issue.

Comment: Definitely yes but i haven't find it yet, i checked extensions but i'm using the exact same. On the vps that doesn't crash a few threads are considered as background processes while none are on the one that crashes. Maybe it's coming from a chrome settings but i haven't modified any between the two.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "why" yet. Can you once again uninstall Chrome, and then restart the VM and install Chrome after to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: While doing that i noticed that the one that doesn't crash has a total virtual memory of 10.6 GB while the other one is 6.99GB. It may be the difference that cause on to work and the other to crash but i don't know where the difference is coming from since both have 5.99GB Ram installed.

Comment: With respect to your most recent comment, check the paging setup for both machines as that affects virtual memory. I had mentioned paging as a possible restriction in machine 2.

Comment: My bad on that one, since english isn't my first language i totaly misunderstood the term "paging". So i allocated the same amount of hard memory and now it seems to behave the same way as the other VM. Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: So I think my answer has helped you here. I added a confirming note in my answer